# What is the difference between tuples and array in rust?

Tags: rust

The only real difference I can figure out after reading the beginner guide, is that in tuple you can have values of multiple types? Both are immutable?

And what are the use cases where I'd want a tuple or array, apart from the obvious one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An array is a list of items of homogeneous type.  You can iterate over it and index or slice it with dynamic indices.  It should be used for homegeneous collections of items that play the same role in the code.  In general, you will iterate over an array at least once in your code.

A tuple is a fixed-length agglomeration of heterogeneous items.  It should be thought of as a `struct` with anonymous fields.  The fields generally have different meaning in the code, and you can't iterate over it.

Answer (score 18):

## Array

- collection of values of the same type
- fixed-sized collection

### Accessing element

You can access element of array by array's name, square brackets, and index, ex:

```
let arr = [22, 433, 55];
assert_eq!(arr[0], 22);
```

### Destructuring arrays

Arrays can be destructured into multiple variables, ex:

```
let arr = [1, 42 ,309];
let [id, code, set] = arr;

assert_eq!(id, 1);
assert_eq!(code, 42);
assert_eq!(set, 309);
```

## Tuple

- collection of values of different types
- finite heterogeneous sequence

### Accessing element

You can access element of tuple by tuple's name, dot, and index, ex:

```
let tup = (22, "str", 55);
assert_eq!(tup.0, 22);
```

### Functions

Tuples may be used to return multiple values from functions, ex:

```
fn num(i: u32) -> (i64, u32) {
    (-33, 33 + i)
}

assert_eq!(num(12), (-33, 45));
```

### Destructuring tuples

Tuples can also be destructured and it's more common practise to destructure tuples rather than arrays, ex:

```
let tup = (212, "Wow", 55);
let (num, word, id) = tup;

assert_eq!(num, 212);
assert_eq!(word, "Wow");
assert_eq!(id, 55);
```

Useful resources:

- [Compound Types - The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-02-data-types.html#compound-types)
- [Tuples - Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/tuples.html)
- [Arrays and Slices - Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/array.html)

Comment: As a side not, fixed-length arrays can also be destructured – that's not really a difference between the two types.  It is a lot more common to destructure tuples, though.

Comment: I'd said that the most important difference was shown in the other answer: array can be iterated, sliced, indexed by variable, etc., and all we can do with tuples is destructuring and constant indexing. Arrays are limited in content, but much more flexible in usage, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

**Tuples:**

- Items can be heterogenous types
- Fixed number of items
- Indexing via `.` syntax e.g `myTuple.0` for first element
- Mutable only with `mut` keyword

**Arrays:**

- Item are same type
- Fixed number of items
- Indexing via `[]` syntax e.g `myArr.[0]` for first element
- Mutable only with `mut` keyword

**Example:**

For the example I have declared the types explicitly so you can the what types the variables are. In your code you can leave them out
usually since the compiler will infer them.

```
fn main() {
    let mut tupleA: (i32, i32, &str) = (3434, 5634, "abc");    
    let tupleB: (char, i32, bool) = ('d', 456, false);    

    let mut arrayA: [i32; 3] = [1,2,3];
    let arrayB: [bool; 4] = [false, true, false, true];

    tupleA.1 = 5;
    arrayA[0] = 5;

    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?} {:?}", tupleA, tupleB, arrayA, arrayB)
    // prints (3434, 5, "abc") ('d', 456, false) [5, 2, 3] [false, true, false, true]

}
```