# Rust, type definition of vector of tuples

Tags: arrays, syntax, rust

I am following the excism rust track, and I've hit a problem (I'm very, very new to rust)

This is a function to calculate the pythagorean triples of an integer:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub fn find(sum: u32) -> HashSet<[u32; 3]> {
    let a_b_plus_c: Vec<(u32; 2)> = (1_u32..(sum / 3_u32)).into_par_iter()
        .filter_map(|a| {
            let b_plus_c: u32 = sum - a;

            let whole_number_check: Option<u32> = (b_plus_c.pow(2) - a.pow(2)).checked_rem(b_plus_c * 2);

            match whole_number_check {
                Some(0) => Some((a, b_plus_c)),
                Some(_) => None,
                None => None,
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<(u32; 2)>>();

    a_b_plus_c.into_par_iter().filter_map(|a, b_plus_c| {
        let b: u32 = (b_plus_c.pow(2) - a.pow(2))/(b_plus_c * 2);
        let c: u32 = b_plus_c - b;

        match b {
            b if b > a => [a, b, c]
            _ => None,
        }}
        ).collect::<HashSet<[u32; 3]>>();

}
```

Or rather, it would be if it worked...

The current issue is in the line:

```
let a_b_plus_c: Vec<(u32; 2)> = (1_u32..(sum / 3_u32)).into_par_iter()
```

It says that it expected one of a number of symbols when parsing the type for `a_b_plus_c`, but found `;`. From everything that I've seen (not much), this is the correct way to define a vector of tuples, each of which has two elements of type `u32`.

As I said, this is a learning exercise for me, so if anybody could help me out, I would be grateful for verbose and detailed answers :)

For what it's worth, as it might help you to comment on my code, this is the maths:

```
a + b + c = sum
a² + b² = c²
Rearrange for b:
b = ((b + c)² - a²) / (2(b + c))
So, iterate through a to get b+c, since (b+c) = sum - a
Then solve the above equation to get a, b+c, and b
Confirm that a < b
Then solve for c:
c = (b + c) - b
```

It should then spit them all out into a HashSet of arrays of `a,b,c`

Comment: Either `(u32, u32)` or `[u32; 2]`.

Comment: @hellow Won’t the latter give me a vector of arrays, rather than a vector of tulles?

Comment: It will give you an array of two `u32`s. A [`Vec is a type`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Ok, but I need a vector of tuples (of 2 u32s) a simple two element array won’t work. This is to store the result of collect() on a iterator, it doesn’t store only two values...

Comment: IMHO they are interchangeable https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903936/1021920 also I told you what the correct syntax is ^^

Comment: Oh, fair enough, so you would suggest Vec<[u32, 2]>?

Comment: The fun thing is, you don't need to specify it at all. Your code looks very unrusty and I took a minute to "convert it to more rusty code" https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=712f64ce51a7590039ad560a6783db7a
As you see, you don't need to specify `(u32, u32)` at all, because the compiler will deduce the types for you. I recommend you to read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) because as it seems, you are missing some key features coming with rust. Have fun nevertheless!

Comment: @hellow thank you so much for converting it, it’s helpful to look at code from somebody who knows what they’re doing. I am aware that a couple of the type definitions are optional in my code, but I come from python, so I’m not really used to thinking too much about types. I thought that by writing the types explicitly, it would help me to confirm that what I think is happening, is what the compiler is actually doing!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, your code does not work correctly for e.g. 25 if I understand correctly what you are doing (`25 = 16 + 9 = 5² = 4² + 3²`)

Comment: @hellow I don’t think that’s what it’s trying to do. I’ll investigate and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @hellow If you're interested, it does actually work. It takes some number S, and computes a pythagorean triple - a, b, and c such that a + b + c = S. 25 seems to have no solutions for this problem. As an example, 1000 gives 200, 375, 425, which is a pythagorean triple, and whose sum is 1000

Comment: But as  already  stated,  25 is a valid triplet.

Comment: Yes, 25 is a valid triplet, but 3+4+5 sums to 12, and, indeed, if you run the algorithm on 12, it returns 3,4,5, as expected

Answer (score 5):

You should enumerate each tuple's element type in definition. This should work:

```
let a_b_plus_c: Vec<(u32, u32)> = (1_u32..(sum / 3_u32)).into_par_iter()
```